# error: integer required readlines()

Tags: python

I'm trying to open a CSV document using `readlines()` in Python.

The document contains a list of words, but I'm getting the error that an integer is required. Here's what I wrote and the error message I received:

```
>>> f = open('mike_only_genes.csv')
>>> a = f.readlines('mike_only_genes.csv')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are calling it wrong:

```
f.readlines('mike_only_genes.csv')
```

should be:

```
f.readlines()
```

Answer (score 1):

Because readlines can be executed alone or with an integer, if you want to read all lines, just use readlines().

```
with open('mike_only_genes.csv') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

Read more about [readlines](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=readlines#file.readlines) method: if sizehint parameter is specified than '*sizehint bytes (possibly after rounding up to an internal buffer size) are read*', but you have specified a string that is why it throwing an exception about integer value:

```
f = open('mike_only_genes.csv') 
a = f.readlines()
```

OR use:

```
with open('mike_only_genes.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        # do something
```

OR:

```
for line in open('mike_only_genes.csv'):
    # do something
```